# Field does not exist ERROR 000728 from ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, error-000728

The X Coordinates and Y Coordinates exist in the csv. However, I still get this error. Can anyone help?

> ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
> ERROR 000728: Field X Coordinates does not exist within table
> ERROR 000728: Field Y Coordinates does not exist within table
> Failed to execute (MakeXYEventLayer)

```py
# Description: Creates an XY layer and exports it to a layer file

# import system modules 
import arcpy
import csv

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/GEO345/Lab4/Lab4/"
 
# Set the local variables
in_Table = "C:\\GEO345\\Lab4\\Lab4\\Crimes_-_2010.csv"
out_Layer = "crime_2010_layer"
saved_Layer = r"c:\GEO345\Lab4\Lab4\crime_2010.lyr"

# Set the spatial reference
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

# Make the XY event layer...
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(in_Table, 'X Coordinates', 'Y Coordinates', out_Layer, 
                                  sr)

# Save to a layer file
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(out_Layer, saved_Layer)
```

Comment: probably a problem with the space in the field name, which could be confused with a field separator Try renaming your fields as Xcoordinates Ycoordinates

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is what it was.

Comment: @radouxju I think you should write up a brief answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field names contain spaces, which are non standard characters. Those special characters often cause problems, so you should either completely remove the space between X/Y and Coordinates, or replace it with "_" e.g. XCoordinates or X
_Coordinates